# Javascript (dynamic) insert into array, then shift all elements underneath +1

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Didn't really found a solution to this for Javascript.
What I need; I want to insert an element into an array, but not really overwrite that element. Rather a 'dynamic' insert. Thus Insert element, then shift all elements underneath it by +1 index.

For instance:

```
I have an array "14S" "16S" "19S".
I know want to insert "15S".
The resulting array: "14S" "15S" "16S" "19S"
```

What i tried:

```
  fullName = "15S"
  low = 5;
  cardsS[low] = fullName;
  for (var i = low; i < cardsS.length; i++) {
      cardsS[i + 1] = cardsS[i];
  }
```

Comment: why not push() and than sort() the array? what are your requirements for the insertion? how do you choose the index?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**If you know the position you want to insert the element into:**

Use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method. It's cheap and works exactly like you want. You can also insert multiple elements at once:

```
var strings = ["14S", "16S", "19S"];
strings.splice(1,0,"15S");
```

Result

```
"14S" "15S" "16S" "19S"
```

You should also use this solution if you don't want the array to be sorted in a specific way.

**If you don't know the position you want to insert the element into:**

You will have to resort to a [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)/[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) combination, supplying your own sort algorithm (unless the standard sort is enough)

```
var strings = ["14S", "16S", "19S"];
strings.push("15S");
strings.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
        return -1;
    if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
        return 1;
    // a must be equal to b
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: What are the differences between splice and push/sort ?

Comment: Both work, but I'd believe `splice` is faster, since it doesn't have to run an expensive sort algorithm. Also, if you don't want your array to be sorted, the `push/sort` method won't work.

Comment: However like, ZenMaster said in the comment to Marc's answer, you have to know where you want to insert the element. It depends on your what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.splice` to insert a value:

```
var arr = ["14S","16S","19S"];
arr.splice(1,0,"15S");
//         ^position after which to insert
//            ^number of elements to delete (none here)
//              ^value to insert ("15S" here)
// => arr is now ["14S","15S","16S","19S"]
```

If you don't know the position, you could use `Array.indexOf` to determine it:

```
var arr = ["14S","16S","19S"];
arr.splice((arr.indexOf('14S')>-1 && arr.indexOf(after)+1 || 0),0,"15S");
//         ^use indexOf result if applicable or just insert 
//          (so, if no position, this turns into unshift ;)
```

You can create a method for it:

```
function arrayInsertAfter(array, after, value){
  after = array.indexOf(after)>-1 && array.indexOf('14S')+1 || 0;
  array.splice(after, 0, value);
  return array;
}
// usage
var arr = arrayInsertAfter(["14S","16S","19S"],"14S","15S");
// => ["14S","15S","16S","19S"]
```

[**MDN link for Array.splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 3):

you just need to use `push()` and then `sort()` functions :

```
var yourArray = ['14S', '16S', '19S'];

yourArray.push('15S');
yourArray.sort();
```

Comment: Seems logical :D what whould be the difference with splice?

Comment: @PHPnooblet how would you know were to splice? Also, doing an good ole' loop while comparing elements would work just as well.

Comment: Sort is not really working, just tested it. the elements are also "14 S" (with a space in between). Maybe this matters?

Comment: Just tried directly into the Chrome console and the sort seems to works even if i add an element like '14 S'.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsplice).

This splices a new element at position 1.

```
arr.splice(1, 0, '155');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/zZcyS/)

Comment: Why `splice`? Wouldn't it be `push`?

Comment: OP said "Thus Insert element, then shift all elements underneath it by +1 index." `Splice` is the way you do that.

Comment: I know, but you assumed that you know the index. Which I have a feeling the OP doesn't... or this is a very strange issue.

Comment: The OP stated that he wants it at that position. I'm assuming that he knows the index.

Comment: Yes i know the index, i gave low = 5

Comment: That's not the index if you want to insert the new number where you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** function on the native array object.

```
var arr = [];
 arr[0] = "14S";
 arr[1] = "16S";
 arr[2] = "19S";

 arr.splice(2, 0, "15S");
 console.log(arr.join());

The resulting array: 14S, 16S, 15S, 19S
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do that, you will start at cardsS[5], which will have the value of "fullName".
The fact is that your cardsS as 4 values, so your array is 0 to 3. You can see that your array at position 4 is unbind.

Moreover, if you do cardsS[i + 1], you will be at position 6, which is unbind too.

What you have to do is to:

1. Check how many item you have in your array (Lenght, Count)
2. Create a new array with Lenght + 1
3. Check if your new item is > or < to your first item. If it is >, you have to add your first item, if not you have to add your new item
4. Do this until your array is full.

If you don't want to do like that, you can use Splice function, just check it, or use a sort function from javascript library.

Hope this can help you !

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
fullName ="15S"
cardsS = ["14S", "16S", "19S"];
for (var k in cardsS)
{
    if(parseInt(fullName) < parseInt(cardsS[k])){
        cardsS.splice(k,0,fullName)
        break;
    }
}
```

:)

if you think is better:

```
fullName ="15S"
cardsS = ["14S", "16S", "19S"];
for (var k = 0; cardsS.length > k; k++)
{
    if(parseInt(fullName) < parseInt(cardsS[k])){
       cardsS.splice(k,0,fullName)
        break;
    }
```

}

Comment: make it a regular `for` and you'd have it. for-in is not the best way to traverse arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your comments you asked the difference between the splice method and the push+sort method.

Splice just cuts up your array and inserts/deletes values based on index.
Using above mentioned example:

```
var strings = ["14S", "16S", "19S"];
strings.splice(1,0,"15S");
```

This will literally place the "15S" on index 1. This is why there is a remark "If you don't know the position you want to insert the element into:"

In which case the push+sort method comes into play. At this point you don't have to go about counting your elements and making sure you place everything at the right location.
You literally just push your "15S" at the end of the array, and then have the sort() automatically sort everything for you.

This, granted that your array is indeed sortable. Some setups don't really allow you to sort your arrays (Like colors sorted by color in the rainbow ... you can't just sort them using sort()).

In this case KooiInc's response comes into play. At this point you know where your item needs to be. 15S comes after 14S, so you search for 14S, get that index, and use that index to splice.
At this point you still have to calculate yourself what element 15S will have to go after - in my rainbow example you'll have to actively remember where you want to 'insert' which color based on which colors are in your array at this moment.

In your example the values seem to be suited for normal sorting, so i would go with the Push+sort approach a few people mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1,2,4,5,6];
var element = 3, pos=3;

for(i=arr.length-1; i>=pos-1; i--){
    arr[i+1]=arr[i];
}
arr[pos-1]=element;
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain this